# Avoid reprocessing when adding new table to spark join

Tags: apache-spark

I have two tables, A and B, stored as parquet and partitioned by day. Everyday tables A and B receives a new partition.

I have a spark job that runs everyday, performing the folowing steps:

1. Loads A and B
2. Filters A and B by a single day (thus reading only one partition from A and one partition from B).
3. Joins filtered A and filtered B
4. Appends the result to table X, which is also partitioned by date. So each job run will create only one partition of X. If this partition already exists, it is overwritten.

Table X has already 365 partitions, because the job ran for 365 days: from 2022-01-01 to 2022-12-31.

Now I want to include in table X columns from a new table: table C. Thus table X will be a join of tables A, B and C.

I changed the previous spark job, which joined A and B, to now do a join also with table C. With the new code, I ran the spark job to write the 366th partition (2023-01-01).

The 366th partition is good, it has the new columns from table C. But the previous 365 partitions were kept untouched, thus they do not have the new columns from table C.

Now comes the tricky part: is it possible to use the new script to add the new columns from table C to the first 365 partitions **without reprocessing the joins between tables A and B**, which are already processed?

Additional informations:

I am using spark. Tables A, B, C and X are in Hive.

Dataframe `df` contains the join result. To write it, the job does:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("new_partition")

spark.sql(
    f"""INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE {hive_table_name}
        PARTITION (  available_year_id = available_year_id,
         available_month_id = available_month_id,
         available_day_id = available_day_id
        ) SELECT * FROM new_partition"""
)
```

Comment: Why don't you join the 365 partitions with table C and override the existing partitions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible to add the new column without reprocessing the joins between the first two tables.

One option is to consider creating a new table which will represent the join of tables A, B and C including new columns in all partitions.

With this approach, you would avoid the need to reprocess the join for each partition and allow you to have a consistent representation of the data across all partitions.

In cases like this, I like to use freeze the data in versions, like:

Tables A and B: v1 (without the columns)
Tables A, B and C: v2 (with the columns for all partitions)